# Summing/grouping values from an Existing query based on specific fields - Access2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

Fow a while now I am trying to figure out how I can easily retrieve some specific values based on an existing query in Access 2013, the retrieved information will be used in a report.

I've got a query that retrieves all hours made by a person on a specific date, project and company they work for (1 company has 2 internal companies). The existing queries groups these fields.

The result set returns the following format:

[image]

What I want to achieve is the total made hours by 1 person on 1 specific project number in a specific date range. 
For example, I want the total made hours by Person x between the dates 27-8 and 29-8 on project 1000 (companies don't matter). This should the result in:
Project number: 1000, date range: 27-8 / 29-8, person: x, made hours: 6.

Is there a way to achieve this? Perhaps with combining functions in the report itself, or is it also possible to do this 'filtering and summing' only in the query? I tried several things like different ways of grouping, summing, etc. but I am kinda stuck by now.

The existing query looks like this:

```
SELECT bookings.projectnumber, 
       bookings.personid, 
       persons.personname, 
       bookings.date, 
       bookings.madehours, 
       projects.projectcompany 
FROM   (bookings 
        LEFT JOIN projects ON projects.projectnumber = bookings.projectnumber) 
       LEFT JOIN persons ON persons.personid = bookings.personid 
GROUP  BY bookings.personid, 
          bookings.date, 
          bookings.projectnumber, 
          projects.projectcompany, 
          persons.personname, 
          bookings.madehours
```

**Edit Addition:**

The returned result will be showed in a report where the data is grouped per Person. Only the date range will be given as a parameter when opneing the report. 
So for above eample (date range 27-8 / 29-8), it should come like this in the report:

```
-----Person x------
Project: 1000   Made Hours: 6
Project: 2000   Made Hours: 4

-----Person y------
Project: 1000   Made Hours: 4
Project: 3000   Made Hours: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your final goal is just to display the result, then you can just make a report in Access. Access 2010 and further provide native tools in order to sort and group query results.

So if you want this result :

```
-----Person x------
Project: 1000   Made Hours: 6
Project: 2000   Made Hours: 4

-----Person y------
Project: 1000   Made Hours: 4
Project: 3000   Made Hours: 9
```

Then create a report linked to the query. In `Details` section add `Project Number` and `Booked hours`, then in the top menu select the tool `Group and sort`, create a group on `By Person` and add the field controller in the group header.

To filter the report on date range, all you have to do is to link the controls used for the date as a criteria. Just use `WHERE OnDate BETWEEN [startDateControlName] AND [endDateControlName]`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Bookings.ProjectNumber, [From], [To], Bookings.PersonID, Persons.PersonName, sum(Bookings.MadeHours) as Hours
FROM (Bookings LEFT JOIN Projects ON Projects.ProjectNumber = Bookings.ProjectNumber) LEFT JOIN Persons ON Persons.PersonID = Bookings.PersonID
GROUP BY [From], [To], Bookings.PersonID, Bookings.ProjectNumber, Persons.PersonName
WHERE Booking.Date>=[From] and Booking.Date<=[To]
```

This uses parameters for the date range and you can add others for the person and project if necessary.

Comment: This doesn't quite give the required result back. The retrieved date should come back in an report however, the report should show all the persons in the report (persons are grouped) with their corresponding made hours for each project. Using the parameters you can get the right values for 1 specific person or project but not for all of them in 1 recordset (which the report desires).

Comment: Added the above comment in the main post as well for more clarification.